# Why does my buffer return as null in this code?

Tags: java, object, concurrency, locking, nullpointerexception

Code adapted from http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Event_Based_Two_Way_Communication

I'm trying to read to a common buffer with the SerialReader class and send that buffer out over the Serial via the SerialWriter class, however the buffer is showing as null every time Writer is called. The code is initialised using the connect method of TwoWaySerialCommTest(pasted below for reference)

```
public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
            {
                this.out = out;
            }

            public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out, byte[] buffer)
            {
                    this.out = out;
                    this.buffer = buffer;
            }

            public void run ()
            {
                    while(true)
                    {
                            lock.lock();
                            try
                        {
                            dataAvailable.await();
                            System.out.println("Waking up");
                            int i = 0;
                            if (this.buffer != null)
                            {
                                    System.out.println("Buffer isn't empty");
                                    while(buffer[i] != ((byte)'\n') && i < buffer.length - 1)
                                    {
                                            this.out.write(buffer[i]);
                                    }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                    System.out.println("Buffer is null");
                                    System.out.println(this.buffer.toString());
                            }
                        }
                        catch ( IOException e )
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.exit(-1);
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                            finally
                            {
                                    lock.unlock();
                            }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Serial Reader class

```
public static class SerialReader implements SerialPortEventListener
        {
            private InputStream in;
            byte[] buffer;

            public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
            {
                this.in = in;
            }

            public SerialReader (InputStream in, byte[] buffer)
            {
                    this.in = in;
                    this.buffer = buffer;
            }

            public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent arg0) {
                lock.lock();
                    int data;
                    if (buffer != null)
                    {
                     for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
                    {
                            if (buffer[i] != 0)
                            {
                                    System.out.print((char)buffer[i]);
                            }
                    }
                    }
                    buffer = new byte[1024];

                try
                {
                    int len = 0;
                    while ( ( data = in.read()) > -1 )
                    {
                        if ( data == '\n' ) {
                            break;
                        }
                        buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
                    }
                    System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,len));
                    for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++)
                    {
                            if (buffer[i] != 0)
                            {
                                    System.out.print((char)buffer[i]);
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    dataAvailable.signal();
                }
                catch ( IOException e )
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(-1);
                }
                finally
                {
                    lock.unlock();
                }
            }

        }
```

TwoWaySerialCommTest (truncated)

```
    import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
    import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;

    /**
     * This version of the TwoWaySerialComm example makes use of the
     * SerialPortEventListener to avoid polling.
     *
     */
    public class TwoWaySerialCommTest
    {
            static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
            static Condition dataAvailable = lock.newCondition();
            public volatile byte[] buffer;

            public TwoWaySerialCommTest()
        {
            super();
        }


        void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
        {
            CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
            if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
            }
            else
            {
                CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

                if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
                {
                    SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                    serialPort.setSerialPortParams(57600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

                    InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

                    (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out , buffer))).start();

                    serialPort.addEventListener(new SerialReader(in , buffer));
                    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I believed `codereview` is for code that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem seems to be this line:

```
buffer = new byte[1024];
```

I don't think you want to be assigning the local `buffer` to a new byte array there.  This causes the writer to write into its own array and *not* the one passed in that is shared by the reader.  Assigning the `buffer` only affects the local variable inside of the writer.

Also, what stops the input stream from overwriting the `buffer`?  If the line length is more that 1024 you are going to get an array out of bounds exception.

Lastly, you are not writing the `\n` character into the `buffer`.  So the reader is going to print a number of `\0` null characters to the output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I know the buffer will not go over 1024 as I'm using this program as a query | response framework for an arduino sketch. What I'm trying to do with the line you highlight is to replace the current buffer with a new, empty buffer for the next read step. I thought that this would assign the new buffer to the globally accessible buffer as I'm passing the reference of this to the reader and writer in their constructors.

Comment: You are passing in the array @LinuxN00b.  Then you assign it to a new array within the method.  That doesn't change the global array at all.  It is still being used by the reader.

Comment: So in order to achieve what I want I would probably have to pass a reference to the TwoWaySerialCommTest class and access the common buffer to reset it?

Comment: Ugh.  I'd just use `Arrays.fill(buffer, 0);` to set it to be nulls.  Really you should read in the line in the reader and pass a new buffer (or String) over with each request.  This fees like how we did things in C @LinuxN00b.

Comment: Thanks, makes more sense alright I just got a bit of tunnel vision